# SVN Patch file behaviour when applied to out of sync working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, patch

I'm trying to find information around the expected behaviour when applying a patch file to a working copy which is not in sync with the repo.

e.g.
The repo holds a class as follows:

```
class Test {
  public void foo(){        
  }
}
```

Developer A updates this as follows and creates a patch file with this change, and sends the patch file to Developer B

```
class Test {
  public void DevA(){        
  }
}
```

Before Developer B has received the patch file, he has changed the code as follows:

```
class Test {
  public void DevB(){        
  }
}
```

**When Developer B applies Developer A (disregarding that he should read the patch file first), what do we expect the outcome to be?**

The result I see if that the patch file is no longer effective, and I assume that this is because it is unable to remove the line as specified in the patch file, so cannot replace it with the addition?

```
-public void foo(){
+public void DevA(){
```

What happens in my case is the patch is ignored as in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a conflict when applying the patch - I think that you'll get the usual behaviour from [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch), eg:

> ```
> If a conflict is found, patch outputs a warning and brackets the conflict with <<<<<<< and >>>>>>> lines. A typical conflict will look
> ```
>
> like this:
>
> ```
> <<<<<<<
> lines from the original file
> =======
> lines from the patch
> >>>>>>>
> ```

and BeveloperB will have to resolve the conflict manually (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's not what's happening in my case. I've added a screenshot above.